# Is it possible to use destrcturing when declaring class private variables with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Normally when multiple variables are come from the same object I would use

```
const [ foo, bar, foobar ] = [ 'foo', 'bar', 'foobar' ]
```

But in type script, things like

```
class Test {
    private {a,b,c} = tool;
}
```

It doesn't work any more.

Is there a other way?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Object.assign` to achive the same result...

```
class Test {
    private a: number;
    private b: string;
    private c: boolean;

    constructor(arg: { a: number, b: string, c: boolean}) {
        Object.assign(this, arg);
    }
}

const tool = {
    a: 5,
    b: 'str',
    c: true
}

const test = new Test(tool);

console.log(JSON.stringify(tool));
```

The feature to destructure paramters is still [active in discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326).